# Absolute coordinates of UIElement in WinRT

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-runtime, uielement

Cannot find a way to locate absolute position of an `UIElement` in Metro style app. Anybody know the solution?

(the context: I want a Popup to be shown next to the button called it)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should work...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var button = sender as Button;
   var ttv = button.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
   Point screenCoords = ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Kinda ununtuitive but it makes sense, I guess. Thanks for the solution.