# How to move an image pixel by pixel?

Tags: c#, image, win-universal-app

So I have 2 `Image`'s I want the first `Image` to move towards the other `Image` I have both X,Y coordinates, how should this be done if I want it moving pixel by pixel towards the target `Image`?

Bare in mind, I'm using `Windows-Universal` I've tried `DoubleAnimation` but my knowledge in that stuff is really bad, I don't know where to start. The `Image` would sometimes have to move diagonally (across) rather than moving right then up.

How should I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
    private void MoveToTarget_Start()
    {
        moveToTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        moveToTimer.Tick += MoveToTarget_Tick;
        moveToTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        moveToTimer.Start();
    }

    void MoveToTarget_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to know how many pixels you need to move. For that, we can try to retrieve the absolute position of each element and compare them (there may be a more straightforward way, I just don't know how):

```
private Point GetAbsolutePosition(UIElement element)
{
   var ttv = element.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
   return ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
}
```

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12164812/869621))

From there, we retrieve the point of each element and compute the difference:

```
var position1 = GetAbsolutePosition(Image1);
var position2 = GetAbsolutePosition(Image2);

var offsetX = position2.X - position1.X;
var offsetY = position2.Y - position1.Y;
```

Now, we now of how many pixels we'll have to move on each axis. We add the `TranslateTransform` for the element (it may be better to do that beforehand directly from the XAML):

```
var translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
image1.RenderTransform = translateTransform;
```

Finally, we create the animations, and target the `TranslateTransform`. Then we group them in a Storyboard, and start it:

```
var animationX = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    From = 0,
    To = offsetX,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
};

var animationY = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    From = 0,
    To = offsetY,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
};

Storyboard.SetTarget(animationX, translateTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationX, "X");

Storyboard.SetTarget(animationY, translateTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationY, "Y");

var storyboard = new Storyboard();

storyboard.Children.Add(animationX);
storyboard.Children.Add(animationY);

storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: This does start an animation, the `Image` I want moving just moves up a pixel and down a pixel, however it doesn't go to the target `Image`. The thing is, my main `Grid` is split into 3 `Columns`, the `Image` I want moving is in `Column 1` and the `Image` I want it moving to is in `Column 3` would this be the cause of this?

Comment: @KTOV This shouldn't be a problem since we're using the absolute position. Could you check that the position returned by `GetAbsolutePoint` is correct? That part is just some code I've taken from another question, I didn't test it

Comment: Yup it works perfectly! Just to let you know, in your answer you need to change `var offsetY = position2.Y - position2.Y;` to `var offsetY = position2.Y - position1.Y;` also in the `GetAbsolutePosition()` it has a fixed `button` rather than using the passed in `element`

Comment: @KTOV Fixed. Thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 1):

To be honest the best idea is to use DoubleAnimation and Storyboard classes.
I would set background as Canvas then You can animate it throught Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop properties.

First You should create DoubleAnimationC class

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation()
{
  SpeedRatio = 3.0,
  AutoReverse = false,
  From = 0 
  To = 100
  BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x),
};


Storyboard.SetTarget((Timeline)doubleAnimation, YOUR IMAGE);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
```

Of course change those properties as You like and now we must create StoryBoard class which will contains our animation

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(da);
sb.Start();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Whem you say "I would set background as Canvas" what do you mean?

Comment: Animating the canvas position is a bad idea, as it will recompute the layout every time, and therefore not benefit from hardware acceleration. It's better to use a `TranslateTransform` to move the element

Comment: In toolbox You can find Canvas